# aws describe volume and query multiple tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to query on a single aws ebs volume from clifor multiple tags of specific volume. How can I frame cli to query multiple tags of specific ebs volume?

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-12345 --query 'Volumes[].Tags[?Key==`InstanceName`].[?Key==`TeamOwner`]'
```

Comment: What's wrong with with current command?

Comment: @Marcin...Above command throws error. check out below command to query only one tag name "InstanceName". I want to query for tags of specific ebs volume.

aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-12345 --query 'Volumes[].Tags[?Key==`InstanceName`]' --output text

Comment: What error? Your question lacks details.

Comment: Below is the error message. @Marcin

Bad value for --query Volumes[].Tags[?Key==InstanceName].[?Key==TeamOwner]: Expecting: ['quoted_identifier', 'unquoted_identifier', 'lbracket', 'lbrace'], got: filter: Parse error at column 35, token "[?" (FILTER), for expression:
"Volumes[].Tags[?Key==InstanceName].[?Key==TeamOwner]"

Comment: @Marcin...have tried to run above query to understand what is problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get two tags as follows:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-12345 --query 'Volumes[].[Tags[?Key==`InstanceName`],Tags[?Key==`TeamOwner`]]' --output text
```